Why is my Catalpa wood blotchy?
I put 1 coat of Matte poly minnwax on my two pieces of Catalpa wood and went down to sand it for a second coat and it’s all blotchy.  What can I do to fix it?  Should I use a different top coat?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We need lots more detail before we can even attempt to answer here, so give us a full rundown on how you prepped the wood prior to applying the finish; don't leave any detail out that you think isn't relevant, on the off chance that it is. Also, in what way(s) exactly is it blotchy? That word means different things to different people, plus it's rare for a clear finish to result in classic blotching (such as pine is prone to for example). We could do with pics! A couple of pics will save you 2,000 words ^_^
